# Apache CXF - share data between In and Out interceptors

Tags: java, cxf

I am using Apach CXF as REST provider.

I want to gather data when I enter the webservice, gather data before I enter the resposne and add some calculation to the response. For this question and for simplicity, lets assume I want to get the starting time on entering, the finishing time before the response is sent and add the total time to the response.

Now, how do I do that? I created In and Out interceptors that works fine alone, but how do I use the data from the In interceptor in the Out interceptor?

Thanks
Idob

## UPDATE:

I tried to set the data as contextual parameter with

```
message.setContextualProperty(key,value);
```

but I am getteing NULL on

```
message.getContextualProperty(key);
```

I also tried the same but just with

```
message.put(key,value) and message.get(key)
```

didn't work.

Idea's anyone?

Thank you,
Idob

Comment: Remember that from exchange you are able to get in message, so share data between in and out interceptor is no needed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can store values on the [`Exchange`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Exchange.html). CXF creates an `Exchange` object for each request to act as a container for the in and out messages for the request/response pair and makes it accessible as `message.getExchange()` from both.

In interceptor:

```
public void handleMessage(Message inMessage) throws Fault {
  inMessage.getExchange().put("com.example.myKey", myCustomObject);
}
```

Out interceptor

```
public void handleMessage(Message outMessage) throws Fault {
  MyCustomObject obj = (MyCustomObject)outMessage.getExchange().get("com.example.myKey");
}
```

(or vice-versa for client-side interceptors, where the out would store values and the in would retrieve them). Choose a key that you know won't be used by other interceptors - a package-qualified name is a good choice. Note that, like `Message`, `Exchange` is a `StringMap` and has generic put/get methods taking a `Class` as the key that give you compile-time type safety and save you having to cast:

```
theExchange.put(MyCustomObject.class, new MyCustomObject());
MyCustomObject myObj = theExchange.get(MyCustomObject.class);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure CXF doesn't use more than one thread concurrently to process the same message exchange, so yes it should be safe.  You're not storing any state on the interceptor itself, only on the exchange.

Comment: yes, but in the In interceptor is set message.getExchange().put(Student.class.getSimpleName(), student); and on the out I get message.getExchange().get(Student.class.getSimpleName());
This is the same key. What happens when two processes try to do this on the same time?

Comment: That's why I used `com.example` in my code - it's up to you to pick a name that nobody else will use.  As an aside, `Exchange` implements `StringMap` which provides generic put and get methods where the key is a `Class` that allow `Student stu = message.getExchange().get(Student.class)` with no need to cast.

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, There is only one exchange per application. And unless I would provide a unique key for each exchange put (even on the same class exactly) I can't use it.  If so, It isn't good enough for me because everything is stateless and I can't set a unique key which I could retrieve again later.

Comment: No, there is one `Exchange` per _request_.  You need to pick a key that no other interceptors will use for the same request, but you can reuse the same key from one request to the next,

Comment: Its a pretty late comment but I got the same Q and instead of Out INTERCEPTOR i've got a out FILTER !! anyway is there any way this could work with filters as well???

Answer (score 1):

Your interceptors have access to `javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext`. This extends `Map<String,Object>`, so you can put whatever you want into the context and access it later on in the request:

```
public boolean handleMessage(final MessageContext context) {
    context.put("my-key", myCustomObject);
            // do whatever else your interceptor does
}
```

Later on:

```
public boolean handleMessage(final MessageContext context) {
    MyCustomObject myCustomObject = context.get("my-key");
            // do whatever else your interceptor does
}
```

Comment: But the interceptor must override: public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault.  How does it combine?

Comment: I tried setting: message.setContextualProperty(key, value) but I get null when I try to message.getContextualProperty(key).

Comment: @Idob This works only if your interceptors implement JAX-WS's `javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler`. It won't work if you are implementing CXF-specific `org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptor`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, but message.getExchange().put and get works fine.