# JAX-WS request and response interceptors in same thread as invoke?

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-ws, cxf

I'm wondering if the interceptors for a `SOAP` request sent over `JAX-WS` (CXF/JAXB) are guaranteed to run in the same thread as the invocation happens?

The reason I'm asking is because I want to log the raw requests and responses (XML dumps) to the database using some request ID parameter as a key. And I don't know how to pass this ID to the interceptors, except setting it as a ThreadLocal variable prior to the `JAXB` invocation and retrieving it in the interceptors. Are there any other reasons I'm not seeing which makes this strategy a bad idea?

Comment: You don't need a ThreadLocal, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12690600/116509

Comment: You're right, I was able to solve it using the message exchange, thanks! But I'm still curious as to if there's some way to reliably and conveniently send a request-specific parameter to the interceptors from the part of the code where I perform the actual JAXB method call (e.g. like a transaction ID). Because it seems like the message exchange isn't available outside of the interceptors.

Comment: A threadlocal is the way to go, for that case. If you're using Spring/CDI/some other framework, it will provide request-scoped proxies (that use a ThreadLocal under the covers) to let you do this. You might also want to look at Mapped/Nested Diagnostic Contexts in your logging framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject ServletContext to your service/interceptor classes

```
   @Context 
   private ServletContext context;
```

and get/set attributes from/to context

```
context.getAttribute  
context.setAttribute
```

in this way you can transfer objects between services/interceptors.
also you can use methods

```
Message#getContextualProperty  
Message#setContextualProperty
```

in you interceptors to set/get proprties to/from context